# Syntax Error with INSERT statement. C# Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access

Trying to add a new record to a database. I have tried this type of code on a different project and it worked fine.

I keep getting a Syntax Error on INSERT statement:

[image]

I cannot seem to find the problem. I have searched for ages at other solutions that did not work. I have checked the table names a few times now and I can't see any inconsistencies.

Please note that I do have all the other remaining code to add the record, but didn't include it here.

Any help would be great. If anyone needs anymore information I will gladly comply.

I am working with C# and using Access Database.

```
    void addRecord()
    {

        OleDbConnection myDatabaseConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"Data Source=..\..\Database\TestionRetail.accdb;");
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = myDatabaseConnection;
        myDatabaseConnection.Open();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employee (PayrollNo, Title, FirstName, Surname, Position, DOB, Email, PhoneNumber, AlternateNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Postcode, ContractType)" +
                                            "VALUES (@PayrollNo, @Title, @FirstName, @Surname, @Position, @DOB, @Email, @PhoneNumber, @AlternateNumber, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @City, @Postcode, @ContractType)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollNo", txtPayroll.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", cmbTitle.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", txtPosition.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dtpDOB.Value.ToShortDateString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", txtPhoneNo.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlternateNumber", txtAltPhoneNo.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", txtAddress1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", txtAddress2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtTown.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", mtbPostcode.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractType", cmbContract.SelectedIndex.ToString());

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();


            var item = new NotifyIcon(this.components);
            item.Visible = true;
            item.Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information;
            item.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "Record Added", "Successfully added new record", ToolTipIcon.Info);
            this.Hide();

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
        }

        //5. Close the database 
        myDatabaseConnection.Close();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert Into error c#, access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623274/insert-into-error-c-access)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help everyone, I fixed the problem by putting square brackets in

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a space after the closing parenthesis on the following line:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employee (PayrollNo, Title, FirstName, Surname, Position, DOB, Email, PhoneNumber, AlternateNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Postcode, ContractType)" +
```

Otherwise your query will read:

```
INSERT INTO Employee (PayrollNo, Title, FirstName, Surname, Position, DOB, Email, PhoneNumber, AlternateNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Postcode, ContractType)VALUES (@PayrollNo, @Title, @FirstName, @Surname, @Position, @DOB, @Email, @PhoneNumber, @AlternateNumber, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @City, @Postcode, @ContractType)
```

Which is why it is saying after `INSERT` because that's the first/last keyword it recognises before it encounters a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the, unfortunately that did not seem to resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

A *date* field is not *text*. Thus:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dtpDOB.Value);
```